# RXjava how to universally handle missing error listeners / missing all stack traces on logging

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactive

This has lead to endless painful to root out issues on the project I am working on. In this case I have a down endpoint and I'm getting a 404. In this case, I want nothing to happen as it is not critical and my universal handler logs it.

This Fails. I get a crash, no error logs. Lots of headaches.

```
mDynamicSyncCoordinatior.fetchSpots().subscribe(this::applySpots));
```

Works, the empty error function allows me to proceed as desired.

```
mDynamicSyncCoordinatior.fetchSpots().subscribe(this::applySpots, this::error));
```

This is the DynamicSyncCoordinatior code. getSpots() here is my retrofit function

```
 public Observable<Spots> fetchSpots() {
    Observable<Spots> spotsObservable = mApiGsonService.getSpots()
        .doOnError(getUniversalErrorHandler(mContext, mEventBus));

    return spotsObservable;
  }
```

My expectation that the Universal error handler will deal with my errors and things that are not explicitly handling errors to not cause crashes... I do not want a listener to crash if it is not setup to catch exceptions.

I have an app with dozens of network calls (that I have inherited) like the crash above. What is the cleanest way I can make it so that the subscribers do not need to explicitly ignore network throws? Is there something I can do upstream that will stop it at the Sync Coordinator class?

Thanks! Note I am using RXjava 1, not 2.

Bonus points, if I could just get a STACK TRACE then this would not be such an issue.

Comment: "I get a crash, no error logs" -- I'm fairly certain that you get a stack trace, but it is not logged at error severity. Check lower severity levels. "My expectation that the Universal error handler will deal with my errors and things that are not explicitly handling errors to not cause crashes" -- no, because it does not consume the event.

Comment: I have android studio logcat set to verbose, no filters. Then read it line by line.

Comment: Yes my understanding of RX and the previous developers is at the root of this. I would think that a throwable would not be consumed if I did not set a handler for error states. That said, if there is no way around that. Is there a way to create an observable that ignores errors? The end goal is to not look through 50 network calls and their chains for missing error handlers. The flip of requiring error handlers would also be beneficial.

Comment: Did you write whatever `mApiGsonService` is? If so, perhaps have it catch expected exceptions and return them as part of its result. There may be more RxJava-y ways of approaching the problem, but for expected exceptions, I prefer to catch them early rather than have them ripple though the app.

Comment: That is just just my interface for retrofit  @GET("/foo/bar") Observable<Spots> getHotSpots(); The DynamicSyncCoordinator is where we first interact with the data. All calls in here have an error listener as that is where I filter for unauthorized and other events. It is what calls the fetchSpots functions, that subscribe, but don't set a final Action1<Throwable> that are the issue.

Comment: Yes exactly I want the exception to be handled at the DynamicSyncCoordinatior and go no further. Maybe the best solution is to do the network call, if successful, emit on a second observable, that the activity has subscribed